# Voice recognition based subtitle synchronisation

Tags: voice-recognition

Is there any existing software that allows me to sync an existing subtitle file to a video file based on voice recognition of its audio stream, (fuzzy) mapping it to the textual contents of the subtitle file and adjusting the timestamps in it to match the video file?

Comment: CCExtractor currently develops https://github.com/saurabhshri/CCAligner

Comment: While it seems that the actual goal of CCExtractor is to split up subtitle lines into single words and display them accordingly to the sound stream, using it as a library may be possible for synchronization, thank you.